# i need to SUM column values for the curren month only

Tags: android, sql

Hi everyone i need to get a SUM query to sum only the values from the current month

is there anyway to do that?

```
public  int getTotal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum=0;
        Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT SUM(_value) FROM TableActone", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                sum=cursor.getInt(0);
            }
            return sum;
           }
```

I have this right now, but it gets the SUM of every value on that column !

I want just to sum up the value for november 2013 for instance.

Anyway to do that?

TY all in advance

Edit:

```
public static final String KEY_DATEACTONE = "_date";
```

i have a column where the users inputs the date of the expense. (Its a expense manager app)

The user inputs the date of the expense and i use this method to get the date into de database

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mydate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };

    date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(ActoneSQLentry.this, mydate, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

}

private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; // In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    date.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: I'm assuming the time of the "Actone" is stored somewhere, but it would help if you told us how you're storing it in the rows.

Comment: sure, i'll edit the post! done, hope it helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get monthy data from SQL database choosing the month from a spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078219/get-monthy-data-from-sql-database-choosing-the-month-from-a-spinner)

Comment: njzk2 i is not ! its a different question! i'll explain ! in one activity a need to show the total expense for current month! i'm doing that with a SUM rawquery! on another activity i want to give the possibility to the user to see the database monthwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give it the current month and year. Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(_value)
FROM TableActone
WHERE strftime('%m', date_col) = strftime('%m', (
      SELECT DATE ('now')
      ))
  AND strftime('%Y', date_col) = strftime('%Y', (
      SELECT DATE ('now')
      ))
```

You can see the docs for strftime [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f0a6a/19)</kbd>

Comment: acho que a soluçao é essa simplesmente agora nao me esta a somar nada, provavelmente pq a  data naoo esta bem formatada! tem de estar YY/mm/dd obrigatoriamente? obrigado

Comment: We should speak in english so this can be helpful to more people :). What's the  date's format ? Is it a string?

Comment: Sorry, sure i'll speak in ennglish, my bad, yeah it is a string ! i'm kinda of new to all this and a get confused with a lot of stuff! what code do u need me to show you, so you get all the info?

Comment: Try putting that string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: i'm using this to format   String myFormat = "yy/MM/dd";   should i change it here? as u can see above i'm using a datepickerdialog to get the date into the database.

Comment: Yes. add it there: yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Up and Running ! Thank so much Filipe Silva!